# Errors using DefaultIfEmpty() in LINQ query with group by

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following LINQ (to SQL Server) query:

```
var railcarsByProduct = await (from r in DbContext.Railcars
                               let p = DbContext.ProductAliases
                                   .Where(pa => pa.Product.Company.CompanyCode == companyCode && pa.Alias == r.Product)
                                   .Select(pa => pa.Product.Name)
                                   .FirstOrDefault()
                               where r.Facility.Company.CompanyCode == companyCode && r.Departure == null
                               group r by p into productGroup
                               select new { Product = productGroup.Key, Count = productGroup.Count() }
                              ).ToListAsync();
```

This is working fine. However, there is the possibility that the `ProductAliases` subquery will return null. In that case, I want to default to `r.Product`.

I tried adding `DefaultIfEmpty()` to the subquery.

```
var railcarsByProduct = await (from r in DbContext.Railcars
                               let p = DbContext.ProductAliases
                                   .Where(pa => pa.Product.Company.CompanyCode == companyCode && pa.Alias == r.Product)
                                   .Select(pa => pa.Product.Name)
                                   .DefaultIfEmpty(r.Product)
                                   .FirstOrDefault()
                               where r.Facility.Company.CompanyCode == companyCode && r.Departure == null
                               group r by p into productGroup
                               select new { Product = productGroup.Key, Count = productGroup.Count() }
                              ).ToListAsync();
```

But this gives an error.

> 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(pa => pa.Product.Company.CompanyCode == __companyCode_0 && pa.Alias == r.Outer.Outer.Product)
> .Select(pa => pa.Product.Name)
> .DefaultIfEmpty(r.Outer.Outer.Product)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

Next, I tried handling the null case within the `group by` clause.

```
var railcarsByProduct = await (from r in DbContext.Railcars
                               let p = DbContext.ProductAliases
                                   .Where(pa => pa.Product.Company.CompanyCode == companyCode && pa.Alias == r.Product)
                                   .Select(pa => pa.Product.Name)
                                   .FirstOrDefault()
                               where r.Facility.Company.CompanyCode == companyCode && r.Departure == null
                               group r by p ?? r.Product into productGroup
                               select new { Product = productGroup.Key, Count = productGroup.Count() }
                              ).ToListAsync();
```

But this also gives the exact same error.

I understand could just bring down all the rows and then group them in C# code. But does anyone see a way where I wouldn't need to do that?

Comment: Why are you selecting pa.Product.Name then trying to default to r.Product. Is this what you intended to do?

Comment: @DanielKelsch: I'm selecting `pa.Product.Name` because that's exactly what I want. But as I explained, it's possible the subquery results are empty, and so `FirstOrDefault()` returns null. In that case, I want to use `r.Product`.

Comment: @JonathanWood What EF Core version are you targeting? `DefaultIfEmpty(arg)` is not supported, but your second query `group r by p ?? r.Product` as well as the answer by Daniel work perfectly for me in EF Core 6.0 (`r.Product` is a `string`, right?)

Comment: Add a navigation property `Product.ProductAliases` and it all gets very straightforward..

Comment: is the `Alias` column unique? it should be unique otherwise your design may be bad. If it's unique, your queries can be rewritten to use a `LEFT JOIN` between `Railcars` and `ProductAliases` and you can fallback on the alias (`r.Product`) where the product name is null (I believe it should work that way).

Comment: @IvanStoev: I'm targeting EF Core 6. `DefaultIfEmpty(arg)` does compile without error. It just doesn't work for me. Yes, `r.Product` is a string.

Comment: @GertArnold: I have a navigation property `Products.ProductAliases`. However, there is no direct link between `Railcars` and `Products`.

Comment: @KingKing: I don't get what you're suggesting with a left join. `Alias` is indexed but cannot be unique in my case. You certainly haven't made the case for my design being bad.

Comment: @JonathanWood `Alias` should be unique in combination with some other columns. All those info can be used in the condition for the `LEFT JOIN`. The uniqueness is required to ensure that the result (after joining) is not duplicate (for the left part). I'm pretty sure using left-join should work. But looks like the answer of `Svyatoslav Danyliv` works for you. I think it's a good solution for you already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```cs
var query = 
    from r in DbContext.Railcars
    from p in DbContext.ProductAliases
        .Where(pa => pa.Product.Company.CompanyCode == companyCode && pa.Alias == r.Product)
        .Select(pa => pa.Product.Name)
        .Take(1)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    where r.Facility.Company.CompanyCode == companyCode && r.Departure == null
    group r by p ?? r.Product into productGroup
    select new 
    { 
        Product = productGroup.Key, 
        Count = productGroup.Count() 
    };
```

Comment: In fact, this *does* work. Do you think my problem was the `let` clause, which would be combined into the `group by` clause?

Comment: @JonathanWood I think your original query with `DefaultIfEmpty` being used wrongly (actually because of how EF translates it, simply it does not support that way of using `DefaultIfEmpty`). It's harder to explain why it's not working with the solution of `Daniel Kelsch`. But of course it's all due to EF not supporting or translating the query in the way we think.

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like the below.

```
var railcarsByProduct = await (from r in DbContext.Railcars
                               let p = DbContext.ProductAliases
                                   .Where(pa => pa.Product.Company.CompanyCode == companyCode && pa.Alias == r.Product)
                                   .Select(pa => pa.Product.Name)
                                   .FirstOrDefault() ?? r.Product
                               where r.Facility.Company.CompanyCode == companyCode && r.Departure == null
                               group r by p into productGroup
                               select new { Product = productGroup.Key, Count = productGroup.Count() }
                              ).ToListAsync();
```

Not sure if it will work but I know the DefaultIfEmpty is weird or has been weird with Entity Framework in the past.

Comment: Thanks but I had tried that too. Exact same error.

Comment: @JonathanWood it can't be the exact error as yours because his code does not use `DefaultIfEmpty` as yours, looks like you skimmed too fast